# Linking to a site without SSL on a site with SSL

Tags: php, ssl, hyperlink, connection

I have SSL installed on one of my website, and I'm trying to place a link on the website linking to another of my website that does not have SSL installed. But when clicking on the link, it redirected me to a page that said something like "Your connection is not private. Attackers might be trying to steal your information." Is there any way to override this somehow?

**test.php**

```
<a href = "//www.nossl.com"> wwww.nossl.com </a>
```

^---this is linking to the site without SSL installed.

**Result:**

```
Your connection is not private. Attackers might be trying to steal your information.
```

**Need Result:**

```
Actual website displaying.
```

Comment: This syntax `"//` should only be used when referencing scripts, CSS files, images, etc. and not for href when linking to an external site that doesn't have an SSL certificate installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the full URL:

```
<a href = "http://www.nossl.com"> www.nossl.com </a>
```

Answer (score 6):

You're using a protocol-relative URL, which points to that site with HTTPS (since that's the protocol of the page with the link).

Add `http:` to explicitly make the link point to the non-SSL URL.

Comment: upvoted as this answer also explains _why_ the current code doesn't work

Comment: @JimL Agreed. *"Try this"* types of answers will only feed them for a day, and not for life ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- give a man some code and you help him for a day, teach a man to code and you help him for a lifetime

Comment: @JimL hehe, exactly ;-)